# How to add a item in List View at run time

Tags: android, listview, runtime, addition

I am new at Android and have a list to add and remove items at run time.
I am using the following code to add a new item:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView list;
private Button btAdd;
private ArrayAdapter<String[]> adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list=(ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.ListView1);
    btAdd=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    String [] name={"new Item"};
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String[]>(this,R.id.ListView1);
    adapter.add(name);


    btAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
          {
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
          }

    });   

}
```

What is the problem with this?

Answer (score 2):

1) set your adapter in onCreate: `list.setAdapter(adapter);`

2) Add//Remove your item in your OnClickListener and then call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`

Comment: it is still not working.. in Xml i set android:entries"@array/names" have any problem with that? what are the parameters of to declare Adapter?

Comment: Can you please try :         adapter.add("blahblah");
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: thanks to guide me the actual problem is in Adopter declaration that is adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1); and in Add method pass String[] object not string...

Comment: Have you really tried the method adapter.add(something) or you don't want to try our answers? Click on this link and enjoy: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#add(T)